# Making custom checkboxes work with css - select or check not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not able to select a checkbox and see a check in it. Somehow the css is not connected to the HTML. One of the issues is that the HTML is generated by a Django custom render function, so I'm keeping changes minimal. Here is the HTML:

```
<li class="option table"><div class="option-checkbox"><input id="id_MyJobChoices_0" name="MyJobChoices" type="checkbox" value="_AG" /></div></li>
```

Here is the CSS which renders the checkbox:

```
.option .option-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{display:none}
.option.selected{color:#10a6b8}
.option.selected .check{margin:3px 1px;background:url(check.png) no-repeat;width:16px;height:13px;overflow:hidden}

.option:hover{border:1px solid #0e91a1}
.option:active,.option.selected:active, .option.active{background-color:#0e91a1;color:#fff}

 .option-checkbox {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #E2E2E2;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

I simply cannot see what the issue is. Thanks.

Is there a way without js/jquery. My HTML is rendered from a database so I want this to be as clean as possible and having js/jquery means its going to be messy.

Comment: I don't think you're providing enough HTML with your CSS. I see no elements with an `option` class.

Comment: @BillCriswell Sorry, should be there now.

Comment: Where is your clickhandler that adds the `.selected` class to your `<li>` ?

Comment: Also, where is the element that the `.check` class applies to?

Comment: @SquareCat Do I need a click handler? I thought HTML + css was enough

Comment: I never knew of an approach without javascript. But Bill provided one that seems very good. Use his solution if you don't want to use javascript. Generally you should open up to using javascript. Its not messy, not dangerous and not a problem. Sooner or later you will run into a coding situation where you will need javascript anyway.

Comment: @SquareCat Not against JS and it is there, but these forms are pretty complex as they are being rendered from Django in a custom way. So to keep people happy trying to do it with as few complexities as possible.

Comment: I understand. In that case please try to apply Bills solution.

Comment: @SquareCat Thanks! Sadly Bill does't seem to work!

Comment: It works pretty well for me, also in Chrome.

Comment: Do you get only one checkbox with bills?

Answer (score 1):

I simplified this quite a bit I think. The trick to styling "checkboxes" is to style the label and to use the `+` selector so we can tell when the checkbox is checked. Here's a really simple approach.

```
/* Let's make our checkbox a simple green box! */
label:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* When the input **before** the label is checked, let's adjust it's styling. */
input:checked + label:before {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here's my demo HTML

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" id="foo-003" value="foo-003">
  <label for="foo-003">Foo 003</label>
</div>
```

Here's a demo for you: http://jsbin.com/UvuNaWo/3/edit?html,css,output

It should help get things a bit clearer.

Comment: On chrome, I get the colored checkbox and the standard one.

Comment: Still cannot get rid of the standard checkbox to display just a single checkbox

Comment: Thanks - I'm having a play - trouble is - inherited a very complex style sheet. Ideally all inputs should be on the right of the label - how can we do this?

Comment: Thanks - I'm having a play - trouble is - inherited a very complex style sheet. Ideally all inputs should be on the right of the label - how can we do this?

Comment: Thanks - What should be switched to :right? I would like the label first or left of the checkbox.

Comment: I made a mistake. It should be `:after`. `label:before` -> `label:after`.

Comment: thanks for that - the issue I'm having is how to handle the style sheets around this. For example I have series of containers for the label, and click box, but somehow even using :after I cannot put the order (left to right) such the label is first and the checkbox comes after. If I put the after in, I can change the order of the checkbox, but that checkbox, I cannot seem to control its location - how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that your complete code looks like this:

```
<li class="option table">
    <div class="option-checkbox"><div class="check"></div><input id="id_MyJobChoices_0" name="MyJobChoices" type="checkbox" value="_AG" /></div>
</li>
```

i can generally demonstrate your desired outcome by adding this:

```
// In plain javascript
onclick="document.getElementById('id_MyJobChoices_0').click();this.className=(document.getElementById('id_MyJobChoices_0').checked==true?'option table selected':'option table')"

// or using jQuery
onclick="$('#id_MyJobChoices_0').click();$(this).toggleClass('selected')"
```

to:

```
<li class="option table">
```

resulting in:

```
// In plain javascript
<li onclick="document.getElementById('id_MyJobChoices_0').click();this.className=(document.getElementById('id_MyJobChoices_0').checked==true?'option table selected':'option table')" class="option table">

// or using jQuery
<li onclick="$(this).toggleClass('selected')" class="option table">
```

[See this fiddle for a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/53tBf/1/)

**Please note**

I used a placeholder image, instead of your `check.png` file.

**Hints**

In order to check if the checkbox is currently marked, you can use this:

```
// In plain javascript
document.getElementById('id_MyJobChoices_0').checked

// or using jQuery
$('#id_MyJobChoices_0').is(':checked')
```

I demonstrated this [in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53tBf/1/), too.

Please keep in mind that this solution is just a demonstration - there is still much room for improvement.

Comment: Is there a way without js/jquery. My HTML is rendered from a database so I want this to be as clean as possible and having js/jquery means its going to be messy.

Comment: Not my solution. It requires javascript. Bill's solution seems to work without.