# Is it possible to fully customize a checkbox with CSS and HTML only and no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

This is in response to a question I asked - is it possible to create a fully customizable HTML + CSS checkbox without recourse to using JavaScript. One of the postulated solution is fine, although there is quite a complex style associated with each label/checkbox pair which means the use of `:before` and `:after` do not allow the placement of the checkbox into the right CSS div tag.

Its clearer here I think. Here is the previous question: [Making custom checkboxes work with css - select or check not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446589/making-custom-checkboxes-work-with-css-select-or-check-not-working).

How can I best achieve this with minimal disruption? Already this is a complex project with JavaScript and jQuery and the HTML is output ad rendered by a server - so it needs to be of the the form:

```
<label for="id_MyJobChoices_0">Agriculture
    <div id="left" class="cell">
        <div data-icon-name="chart" class="icon chart"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="center" class="cell">
        <div class="option-text"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="cell">
        <div class="option-checkbox">
            <input id="id_MyJobChoices_0" name="MyJobChoices" type="checkbox" value="_AG" />
        </div>
    </div>
</label>
```

Comment: @MattBall to be able to work within a stylesheet

Comment: @MattBall, what else did you think I would want? Make the tea ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for.  I hide the original button and add a span in the label and use CSS to style it to look like the button.  But you could also use an image and set it as the background of the span to look like the button.  You can put the span on either side of the label text.  This works because the entire label is clickable for a radio button when you use the "for" attribute.

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/QhBrZ/1/

Html:

```
<div id="left" class="cell">
    <div data-icon-name="chart" class="icon chart"></div>
</div>
<div id="center" class="cell">
    <div class="option-text"></div>
</div>
<div id="right" class="cell">
    <div class="option-checkbox">
        <input id="id_MyJobChoices_0" name="MyJobChoices" type="checkbox" value="_AG" /><label for="id_MyJobChoices_0">Agriculture<span></span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
        display:inline-block;
        width:13px;
        height:13px;
        margin:-3px 4px 0 0;
        border-radius:10px;
        border:1px solid #777;
        vertical-align:middle;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.7) inset;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        cursor:pointer;
    }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
        background-color: #29c6ff;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not following - how would I incorporate the style sheet `<div>` tags around the checkbox itself too i.e. within:  `<div id="right" class="cell"></div>`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have used your code to begin with.  I have edited the answer and the fiddle.